# Invalid Token < running browserify on ReactJS code

Tags: reactjs, browserify, babeljs

this is really ridiculous but i'm stuck getting this to run :

```
var React = require('react');
var AppBar = require('./node-modules/material-ui/lib/app-bar') ; 
var Card = require('./node-modules/material-ui/lib/card') ; 

var MyComponent = React.createClass({
    render: function(){
        return (
            <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
        );
    }
});

React.render(
    <MyComponent /> , 
    document.getElementById("header") 
);
```

i tried to follow the docs by installing `browserify` and `babelify` packages and invoking them with respective preset as in [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html), but no matter what combination of options or presets i use, it keeps complaining about "<" characters preceding HTML tags. i tried running it with the es2015 preset as suggested in [this](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/4371) github thread but that didn't help either.

oh and this is the command i invoke and the error it produces:

```
browserify index.jsx -o bundle.js -t babelify --presets es2015 react                                                                                                                              
SyntaxError: /Users/Parsoa/Desktop/Sharif/Homepage/public/index.jsx:      Unexpected token (8:12)
   6 |     render: function(){
   7 |         return (
>  8 |             <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
     |             ^
   9 |         );
  10 |     }
  11 | });
    at Parser.pp.raise    (/Users/Parsoa/Desktop/Sharif/Homepage/public/node_modules/babelify/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:1378:13)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/Parsoa/Desktop/Sharif/Homepage/public/node_modules/babelify/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:2817:8)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprAtom (/Users/Parsoa/Desktop/Sharif/Homepage/public/node_modules/babelify/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:749:12)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprSubscripts (/Users/Parsoa/Desktop/Sharif/Homepage/public/node_modules/babelify/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:504:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeUnary (/Users/Parsoa/Desktop/Sharif/Homepage/public/node_modules/babelify/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:484:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprOps (/Users/Parsoa/Desktop/Sharif/Homepage/public/node_modules/babelify/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:415:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeConditional (/Users/Parsoa/Desktop/Sharif/Homepage/public/node_modules/babelify/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:397:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseMaybeAssign (/Users/Parsoa/Desktop/Sharif/Homepage/public/node_modules/babelify/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:360:19)
    at Parser.pp.parseParenAndDistinguishExpression (/Users/Parsoa/Desktop/Sharif/Homepage/public/node_modules/babelify/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:822:26)
    at Parser.pp.parseExprAtom (/Users/Parsoa/Desktop/Sharif/Homepage/public/node_modules/babelify/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babylon/index.js:708:19)
```

any solutions ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing some square brackets.

```
browserify script.js -o bundle.js -t [ babelify --presets [ es2015 react ] ]
```

Comment: Thanks, so stupid of me! i thought those square brackets meant optional arguments.